# An absolute div inside an inline-block, relative parent div takes width of sibling

Tags: html, css

Consider this markup & styles:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sibling {
  border: 1px dashed green;
}

.tooltip {
  border: 1px dashed purple;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sibling">
    sibling
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip">
    Some text look how skinny it is
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a codepen with the exact stuff](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqJaOZ)

Basically the tooltip seems to take on the width of the sibling--Boooo! I want the tooltip to not have a width at all.

If I remove `display: inline-block;` from the container, the issue is no longer present, but I need the container to be inline-block. So my question is how do I add an absolute positioned div to an inline-block, relative positioned parent div, without the absolute div breaking its text at the width of a sibling div.

**Edit**

The tooltip should also support having a max-width if needed so `white-space: nowrap;` won't work :(

Comment: you can make the `sibling` inline-block instead of the `container`?

Comment: then the parent will be block but i need it to be inline-block

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply removing the `position: relative` from the parent?

Assuming you want the tooltip to show when hovering over the sibling, you could use the following:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.sibling {
  border: 1px dashed green;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vh;
}

.tooltip .content {
  border: 1px dashed purple;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.sibling:hover ~ .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sibling">
    sibling
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip">
    <div class="content">
      Some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="sibling">
    another sibling
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip">
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no vivendum iudicabit per, libris elaboraret ei qui. Mei cibo mollis repudiandae et. Vix ne unum docendi rationibus, doming doctus scripta mei ea. Sed ne zril integre sanctus, cu doming semper omittantur mea. Te adhuc falli ius. Eam ad ceteros nostrum perpetua.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm no I think the container needs to have position: relative; so I can position the tooltip relative to the container if needed.

Comment: I understand your logic, but if you look at my updated answer, you'll see that the tooltip does stay with the container.

Comment: And @rigdonmr I've added an example with `max-width`, per your question edit.

Comment: try adding `top: 5px;` to `.tooltip` though. It's not positioned relative to the container anymore.

Comment: Agreed. But you could add `margin-top` to achieve the same result, with the added benefit of it solving your original width issue.

Comment: okay but say i want the tooltip to be aligned to the right boundary of the sibling (if it were relative, I'd use `right: 0;`). How would i do that with this solution?

Comment: You can’t. That being said, you may want to edit and add this new requirement, plus any others, to your question.

Comment: @rigdonmr, okay one last attempt. If you can modify your `.tooltip` HTML to include a second, nested element, then you can have your `position: relative`, and a more flexible width.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .tooltip {
      border: 1px dashed purple;
      position: absolute;
      white-space:nowrap; /* added */
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but not what I'm looking for unfortunately. I don't want a min width. If the tooltip has only one word, it should be the width of that word.

Comment: yeah so another person suggested white-space: nowrap. The issue is I need to be able to add max-width to the tooltip (say it's 50px). In that case, the text should break after 50px. white-space: nowrap will prevent that

Answer (score 0):

Are you mean you want the text in **tooltip** open the **tooltip**? just add a `white-space: nowrap;` to the `.tooltip`.

Comment: that won't work because i want the tooltip to have a max-width. If the text reaches the max-width, it should wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating tooltip CSS to:

```
.tooltip {
  border: 1px dashed purple;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap; /* add this property.*/
  overflow: hidden; /* add this property.*/
}
```

or Update CSS to

```
.tooltip {
  border: 1px dashed purple;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Change max-width property to width property.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but 2 other people already suggested white-space: nowrap; and I explained why that wouldn't work.